# Python - Strip Punctuation from list of words using re.sub and string.punctuation

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove punctuation from the list of string.punctuation in a list of words. The issue is that I do not know where to strip the punctuation as I am dealing with a dictionary within a dictionary. My code is below

```
from collections import Counter
import re
comments = []
ar_lst = []

for review in reviews:
    ar_dict = {}
    ar_dict["Comments"] = review["Content"]
    ar_dict["Author"] = review["Author"]
    ar_lst.append(ar_dict)
    
for review in ar_lst:
    # TODO: (1) Get the number of words in the current review variable.
    punc= string.punctuation
    comments = review['Comments'].lower()
    author = review['Author']
    unique_words_count = set()
    all_words = comments.split(" ")
    for word in all_words:
        unique_words_count.add(word)
# (2) Print the author's name and the number of (unique) words in his/her review 
    print(f'{author} used {len(unique_words_count)} unique words.')
```

The output I am getting is below

[image]

But I need the output to look like this

[image]

The reason the # of words is off is due to the fact that I can't figure out where to insert the re.sub() expression. I tried putting it into the second 'for-loop' as

`comments = re.sub(punc, '', review['Comments']).lower()`

But this did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, this is a snippet of what the dictionary looks like

[image]

Comment: Please post the data as text instead of images.  You can either strip out punctuation before you split comments, or you can process each `word` in the loop `for word in all_words:`.  As you use a set you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: It's a little unusual to use `string.punctuation` when you can match non-words with things like `\W`

Answer (score 1):

You can either strip out the punctuation from `comments` before you split into it words (preferable), or you can strip it from `word` in the loop `for word in all_words:`.  `string.punctuation` is a string `!"#$%&'...` but you probably want the character set:

```
punc = '[%s]' % string.punctuation.replace(']', '\]')
```